# How to create Hlist from single element by implicit function

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to create a hlist implicitly.

```
case class A(value: Int)

implicit def lift(single: A): A :: HNil = single :: HNil

def something[L <: HList](l: L)(implicit lUBConstraint: LUBConstraint[L, A],
                                isHCons: IsHCons[L]) = {
    println("works")
}

something(A(1) :: A(2) :: HNil) //works
something(A(1)) //not works
something(lift(A(1))) //works
```

something(A(1)) is not working. However, I use intellij idea and It can detect that lift is proper to use here.

Here is the error message from compiler.

> inferred type arguments [Boot.A] do not conform to method something's type parameter bounds [L <: shapeless.HList]
>   [error]   something(A(1)) //not works [error]   ^ [error]
>
> type mismatch; [error]  found   : Boot.A [error] required: L [error] something(A(1))
>
> could not find implicit value for parameter lUBConstraint: shapeless.LUBConstraint[L, Boot.A] [error] something(A(1)

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is there an error? If so, please provide the error as shown.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Scala implicit conversions don't trigger to satisfy type bounds.

You can modify your definition of `something` to allow any such conversions to work:

```
def something[X, L <: HList](x: X)(
  implicit asHList: X => L,
           lUBConstraint: LUBConstraint[L, A],
           isHCons: IsHCons[L]
) = {
    println("works")
}
```

For single argument, this will use your `lift` function, and `<:<` from `Predef` for actual HLists

Comment: Thank you, but will it work for something(A(1) :: A(2) :: HNil) ?

Comment: @Korkor yes, like I said, it will use `<:<` for actual HLists in place of `asHList`